# Difference between these two confusing function pointer notations in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

What is the difference between these two function pointer notations in C?

`void (*a[]())` and `void (*a)()[]`

Do they both represent same - a as an array of pointers to functions - or does the second one represent a pointer to an array of functions?

How should I call these functions - 
say `void (*a[]()) = {swap, add, sub, prod};`?

Does that mean that `a` is an array of function pointers of 4 elements and `swap`, `add`, `sub`, `prod`'s address are there in the `a[0]`...`a[3]`.
How should I invoke these functions, like this?

```
*a[i]()
```

or like this?

```
a[i]()
```

Comment: If you have to ask, you should use a `typedef`. (And even if you don't have to ask, please use a `typedef` anyway.)

Comment: On how to use function pointers, perhaps you should first ask your compiler which form it accepts? Usually compilers are quite good at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) to figure this stuff out until you can do it without thinking about it.

`void (*a[]())`: declare a as array of function returning pointer to void

whereas

`void (*a)()[]`: declare a as pointer to function returning array of void

The latter is invalid C.

Comment: @Eitan Thanks. ridiculous_fish, the author of the site, is one of my favorite bloggers.

Comment: Arrays of functions are invalid in C as well.

Answer (score 5):

They're both invalid.

```
void (*a[]());
```

is interpreted as

```
       a        -- a
       a[]      -- is an array
       a[]()    -- of function
      *a[]()    -- returning pointer
void (*a[]())   -- to void.
```

You cannot declare an array of function type.  Similarly,

```
void (*a)()[]
```

is interpreted as

```
       a       -- a
     (*a)      -- is a pointer
     (*a)()    -- to a function
     (*a)()[]  -- returning an array of unknown size
void (*a)()[]  -- of void.
```

Functions cannot return array types, and you can't have arrays of `void`.

If you want to declare an array of pointers to functions returning `void`, you'd build it up as:

```
       a          -- a
       a[N]       -- is an N-element array
      *a[N]       -- of pointers
     (*a[N])()    -- to functions
void (*a[N])();   -- returning void
```

Thus, `void (*a[N])();` declares `a` as an array of pointers to functions returning `void`.  You'd call each individual function in the array as

```
(*a[i])();
```

or

```
a[i]();
```

although I prefer the first form, even if it is a little more cluttered.

So, given the list of functions `swap`, `add`, `sub`, and `prod`, you'd build up your array as

```
void swap() {...}
void add() {...}
void sub() {...}
void prod() {...}
...
void (*a[])() = {swap, add, sub, prod};
...
(*a[0])(); // calls swap
(*a[1])(); // calls add
```

Given the function names, I assume they take some kind of arguments.  Note that all the function pointers in an array should have the same *signature*; that is, they should all have the same return type, as well as the same number and types of arguments.

When you call a function through a pointer, C allows you to drop the explicit dereference, so you could call those functions as

```
 a[0]();
 a[1]();
```

but I prefer the first form, even if it is visually more cluttered.

Remember that `[]` and function-call `()` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so `T *a[N]` declares an N-element array of pointer to `T`, `T (*a)[N]` declares a pointer to an N-element array of `T`, `T *f()` declares a function returning a pointer to `T`, and `T (*f)()` declares a pointer to a function returning `T`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Right-Left-Rule in C](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) (other reference [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations#right_left_rule)), both expressions are considered invalid by the compiler (and probably by the standard as well).

The first one is a array of functions, the latter is an array of voids.

An array of pointers to functions returning void would be

```
void (*a[])()
```

.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first is valid C?

Comment: Sorry, but my GCC says `error: declaration of ‘a’ as array of functions`. Could you show me in which context it would be valid?

Comment: @glglgl are you sure you typed in the exact declaration in first case?

Comment: @EitanT: I am sure, yes. I typed in `void (*a[]())` with the function `()` inside the other `()`, while [you typed](http://ideone.com/VYmqV) `void (*a[])()` with the `()` outside the other `()`. It is clear that that works...

Comment: @glglg Well it seems that it is _*I*_ that copied the declaration wrong :] I will happily change the downvote into an upvote but I cannot remove the downvote unless you edit your answer somehow.

Comment: @EitanT Slightly changed in order to make the un-downvote work

Answer (score 0):

The second expression is not valid in C, since first it doesn't allow for arrays of `void` and second it doesn't allow a function to return an array.

Comment: Arrays of functions are invalid in C as well.